# React component displaying but returning NaN from custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, remix.run

I am building an app with React/Remix, fly.io for deployment. I have a countdown component and custom hook built in React. I have a custom `useCountdown` hook with the following code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useCountdown = (targetSeconds) => {
    const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(targetSeconds);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setCountDown(targetSeconds);
        }, [targetSeconds]);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [])

    return getReturnValues(countDown);
};

const getReturnValues = (countDown) => {
    const seconds = Math.floor((countDown % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    return seconds;
}

export default { useCountdown }
```

A `CountdownTimer` component with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import DateTimeDisplay from './DateTimeDisplay';
import { useCountdown } from '../hooks/useCountdown';

const ExpiredNotice = () => {
    return (
        <div className="expired-notice">
            <span>Expired!!!</span>
            <p>Please select a future date and time.</p>
        </div>
    );
};

const ShowCounter = ({ seconds }) => {
    return (
        <div className="show-counter">
                <DateTimeDisplay value={seconds} type={'Seconds'} isDanger={false} />
        </div>
    );
};

const CountdownTimer = ({ targetSeconds }) => {
    const [seconds] = useCountdown(targetSeconds);

    if (seconds <= 0) {
        return <ExpiredNotice />;
    } else {
        return (
            <ShowCounter
                seconds={seconds}
            />
        );
    }
};

export default CountdownTimer;
```

Finally, a `DateTimeDisplay` component with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';

const DateTimeDisplay = ({ value, type, isDanger }) => {
    return (
        <div className={isDanger ? 'countdown danger' : 'countdown'}>
            <p>{value}</p>
            <span>{type}</span>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DateTimeDisplay;
```

And I display it on `index`:

```
import Canvas from '../components/Canvas'
import Drawer from '../components/Drawer'
import LeftToolbox from '../components/LeftToolbox'
import CountdownTimer from '../components/CountdownTimer';

export default function App() {
    let seconds = 90
  return (
      <div className="overscroll-contain overflow-y-hidden h-screen w-screen">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen w-screen bg-slate-800 z-40">
              <LeftToolbox />
              <div className="min-w-[320px] max-w-[640px] position absolute border border-[1rem] border-red-400 rounded-lg">
                  <CountdownTimer targetSeconds={seconds} />
                  <Drawer />
                  <Canvas />
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

The component displays, however instead of displaying an integer within the countdown component, it displays NaN and, in the console, it throws this error:

```
Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.
    at p
    at div
    at DateTimeDisplay (http://localhost:3000/build/routes/index-AU5NYGLP.js:173:26)
    at div
    at ShowCounter (http://localhost:3000/build/routes/index-AU5NYGLP.js:204:22)
    at CountdownTimer (http://localhost:3000/build/routes/index-AU5NYGLP.js:213:25)
    at div
    at div
    at Drawer (http://localhost:3000/build/routes/index-AU5NYGLP.js:227:72)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at App
    at RemixRoute (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-PXAPBAZS.js:2523:3)
    at Outlet (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-PXAPBAZS.js:730:26)
    at body
    at html
    at App
    at RemixRoute (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-PXAPBAZS.js:2523:3)
    at Routes2 (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-PXAPBAZS.js:2506:7)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-PXAPBAZS.js:734:15)
    at RemixCatchBoundary (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-PXAPBAZS.js:1019:10)
    at RemixErrorBoundary (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-PXAPBAZS.js:944:5)
    at RemixEntry (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-PXAPBAZS.js:2403:12)
    at RemixBrowser (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-PXAPBAZS.js:3081:27)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [seconds] = useCountdown(targetSeconds);
```

Change this to this

```
const seconds = useCountdown(targetSeconds);
```

Comment: I did try this, and got the same error